# Element deleted from the array but v-for doesn't update VUEJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, v-for

Guys so I'm trying to develop this rule component which can be spawned by my main component as many times as he wants but the problem is that when I delete an index from the list that tracks the number of rules, the vuejs layout doesn't update accordingly. What I mean by this is that if I check the array it self it deleted the correct item but when I look at the vue page (HTML) it either doesn't delete anything or only deletes the last item, and this may be caused by the `v-for` not updating on list change but I don't know how to solve this.

NewTask.vue (Parent)

```
<template>
  <div class="mt-4">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="if-condition container-fluid d-flex flex-row ps-0">
              <span class="text-center me-2 condition rounded">IF</span>
              <select class="form-select form-select-sm me-2 if-select" v-model="if_condition">
                <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
                <option value="ANY">ANY</option>
                <option value="NONE">NONE</option>
              </select>
              <span>of these filters match</span>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-2 ps-3 pt-3 pb-3 border">
            <new-rule v-for="(item, index) in rules"
                      :key="JSON.stringify(index)" v-on:remove-rule="removeRule(index)"
                      :data="item" :index="index" v-on:data-changed="dataChanged"
                      class="mb-2"/>
            <div class="mt-2 add-rule-div">
              <button class="btn add-rule-btn" v-on:click="addRule">+</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Rule from '@/components/rule'

export default {
    name: "NewTask",
    components: {
      'new-rule': Rule
    },
    data: function () {
      return {
        if_condition: 'ALL',
        rules: []
      }
    },
  methods: {
      dataChanged(data) {
        const rules = this.rules;
        const index = data.index;
        delete data['index'];
        rules.splice(index, 1, data)
        this.rules = rules;
      },
      removeRule(index) {
        const rules = this.rules;
        rules.splice(index, 1)
        this.rules = rules
      },
      addRule() {
        const new_rule = {
          type_input_text: null,
          type_input_show: null,
          rule_input_text: null,
          rule_input_show: null,
        }
        this.rules.push(new_rule)
        console.log(this.rules)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

rule.vue (Child)

```
<template>
    <div class="if-condition d-flex flex-row">
      <select class="form-select form-select-sm me-2"
              v-on:change="checkTypeSelect" v-model="type_select">
        <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
        <option value="XPATH">XPATH</option>
        <option value="ID">ID</option>
        <option value="CLASS">CLASS</option>
      </select>
      <input v-if="type_input_show" type="text" class="form-control me-2" v-model="type_input_text" v-on:change="dataChanged">
      <select class="form-select form-select-sm me-2"
              v-on:change="checkRuleSelect" v-model="rule_select">
        <option value="CONTAINS">CONTAINS</option>
        <option value="EXISTS">EXISTS</option>
      </select>
      <input v-if="rule_input_show" type="text" class="form-control me-2" v-model="rule_input_text" v-on:change="dataChanged">
      <button class="btn remove-rule-btn pb-0 pt-0 ps-2 pe-2" v-on:click="this.$emit('remove-rule')">-</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "rule",
  props: {
    data: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    },
    index: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      type_select: 'HTML',
      type_input_text: '',
      rule_select: 'CONTAINS',
      rule_input_text: '',
      //
      type_input_show: false,
      rule_input_show: true,
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    if (this.data.type_select) {
      this.type_select = this.data.type_select
      this.checkTypeSelect()
    }
    if (this.data.type_input_text) {
      this.type_input_text = this.data.type_input_text
    }
    if (this.data.rule_select) {
      this.rule_select = this.data.rule_select
      this.checkRuleSelect()
    }
    if (this.data.rule_input_text) {
      this.rule_input_text = this.data.rule_input_text
    }
  },
  methods: {
    dataChanged() {
      const new_data = {
        index: this.index,
        type_select: this.type_select,
        type_input_text: this.type_input_text,
        rule_select: this.rule_select,
        rule_input_text: this.rule_input_text
      }
      this.$emit('data-changed', new_data)
    },
    checkTypeSelect() {
      const type_select = this.type_select;
      this.type_input_show = type_select !== 'HTML';
      this.dataChanged()
    },
    checkRuleSelect() {
      const rule_select = this.rule_select;
      this.rule_input_show = rule_select !== 'EXISTS';
      this.dataChanged()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Some images to demonstrate the issue:

Array Before Index delete:
[image]
[image]

Array After Index delete:
[image]
[image]

For further investigation feel free to visit the repo: https://github.com/DEADSEC-SECURITY/Easy-Scraper

**THIS IS NOT PUBLICITY, I TRULY NEED HELP**

Comment: `:key="JSON.stringify(index)"` <- why `JSON.stringify()`? In any case, the issue here is using `index` as the key. When you do that, as far as Vue is concerned when the array changes size it's only ever adding / removing elements from the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the index as a key. VueJS updates the DOM based on the change in key. So you have two options:

- Use some distinct data from each entry or combination as a key.
- Provide no key because as per Vuejs [docs](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/key-attribute.html#key-attribute) you need not provide a key anymore.